# Is it possible to serialize and deserialize a void pointer to & from a blob in a database?

Tags: database, serialization, visual-c++, blob

I would like to store a void pointer in a blob for a record in a table. Is this possible, and if so, how do I do it?

I'm using VC++.

Comment: What programming language are you using? c?

Comment: I'm sorry, but JavaScript doesn't support serializing pointers.

Comment: That all depends on underlying database API you are using. SQLite for example has `sqlite3_bind_blob()` function.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I know is the pointer returned by the function SQLBindCol in SQL Call Level Interface and ODBC API.